# Zipline import error. No module named zipline.transforms

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, importerror, zipline

I am not able to import the zipline.transforms module

```
>>> from zipline.transforms import batch_transform
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'zipline.transforms'
```

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm currently a maintainer of Zipline.

I'm guessing the reason you're seeing this error is because that particular module was removed a while back (assuming you're using zipline 1.0.0 or later). If you want to do things similar to `transforms` you'll need to call `data.history()` to get your pricing data, and call numpy/pandas functions like `.avg()` or `.std()`, or use `talib`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should firstly print out your `sys.path` (`print sys.path`), and then see where you zipline module is installed (somewhere like  *.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipline*).  Usually "no module named XXX" is caused by you `sys.path` doesn't contain the path you installed zipline.  You should just add your zipline path into `sys.path`.  Also use anaconda is good for zipline (http://www.zipline.io/install.html), so as to keep the environment tidy and clean.